# Effectively disable Sort() within a CompareTo() override?

Tags: c#, vb.net, sorting, collections, icomparer

The `CompareTo()` method for my class is dynamic, and can range from a simple comparison to comparisons on a number of columns. This is all determined at run time, and it works great.

But in some cases, I want any attempt to sort a collection of my objects using the default comparison to just do nothing.

Having `CompareTo()` just return a 0 for any comparison, to my surprise, doesn't work. The list gets rearranged in some odd, seemingly-random order.

Is there a way to do this in the `CompareTo()` method implementation? I'd rather not handle this up at the collection level by having to override Sort().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because QuickSort is not a [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_sort#Stability).  I don't see a good option to fix this in the CompareTo method unless you can somehow obtain the index of the element.

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense. I expected that was the case, but Data Algorithms class was so long ago...

Answer (score 0):

I haven´t proved it, but as a suggestion, what if you try to return always 1, or always -1?

Comment: This violates the properties of the CompareTo method:

If A.CompareTo(B) returns a value other than zero, then B.CompareTo(A) is required to return a value of the opposite sign.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override `Sort()`.  The default implementation of `Sort()` offers no guarantees about how it will use `CompareTo()` to arrive at a sorted collection, so there isn't any way to use it to make `Sort()` do the right thing.